# python 3.4.3 basic return issue

Tags: python, return

Below is the basic code from a 2.x tutorial I'm looking at while I'm starting off on 3.4.3:

**Below is the function**

```
def hello():
    print ("hello")
    return 1234
```

**And here is the function being used**

```
hello()
```

The tutorial states that the program should print "Hello" on the top line, and then "1234" directly below it, yet in 3.4.3 it just returns "Hello" without "1234".  What exactly does return do?  Does it store "1234" as a string to be used behind the scenes or something?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Change your function call from `hello()` to `print (hello())` and voila! It will work as described

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, problem solved!  I'd upvote everyone if i had enough reputation =).

Comment: Remember to come back when you have enough rep! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `hello` function, the code prints "hello" and then returns the result `1234` to the caller. If this result (1234) is not printed to the console, nothing else is added and the program will go on without displaying the returned number.

In order to display the number (**1234**), you have to rewrite your code like this:

```
def hello():
    print ("hello")
    return 1234

print(hello())
```

or

```
def hello():
    print ("hello")
    return 1234

result = hello()  # store the result to a temporary variable
print(result)     # print the value stored in the variable
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not print `1234` you only return it. If you do `print(str(hello()))` both will be printed

`Return` is a keyword that is basically giving a value to a method rather than have it return void or no value. When you call a method with a return keyword you are accessing that value but nothing happens if you do nothing with it.

Example

```
i = 0
i = hello()
```

`i` now equals `1234` because `hello()` returns it. Along with that it will execute all the code between method heading and return keyword. "hello" will also be printed.

**Code after return will not be printed**

Answer (score 0):

What print() is doing is also known as "side effect" -- that is, something other than returning stuff. In order to see what's returned by your function, you need to save this returned result in a variable, as JGerulskis has suggested, and then print it. Simply calling hello() will only result in "hello" being printed.

Answer (score 0):

The command return, Returns a value to where it was called

so you could do `print(str(hello()))` which will print the string value of what is returned in this case an integer is returned so we use `str()` to convert it to a string and then print that returned value.

You could also save the returned value, so like `x = hello()`

And you could also compare that value like `if hello() == 1500:`

So just to summarise, return does what it says and returns the value that it is told to return, which can be used with all data types, so that could be, integers, booleans, strings, floats (or i believe a binary value, correct me if I'm wrong)